# city selection in flutter weather app - Flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, openweathermap, weather-api

hope you doin' well
I'm a newbie to flutter and I'm working on a basic weather app as a starter. now, somehow everything is okay, except the city name. I don't know how to implement city search feature and get data from api based on the location. In my code, I defined city name manually.
here is my code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:hava_chitor/Carousel.dart';
import 'package:hava_chitor/UnderCarousel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var temp;
  var name;
  var humidity;
  var description;
  var city = 'London';

  CarouselController buttonCarouselController = CarouselController();

  Future getWeather() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&units=metric&appid=apikey");
    var results = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      this.temp = results['main']['temp'];
      this.name = results['name'];
      this.humidity = results['main']['humidity'];
      this.description = results['weather'][0]['main'];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getWeather();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hava Chitor?',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff424242),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('kir');
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add_circle_outline,
                  color: Color(0xff5d5f64),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xff5d5f64)),
          title: Text(
            'Hava Chitor?',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff5d5f64),
                fontFamily: 'Sans',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Carousel(name),
              UnderCarousel(temp, description, humidity),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-weather-app-using-provider-c168d59af837 check out this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a TextField and a TextFieldController and call the function getWeather when the user finish writing the city name, something like this

```
  String city;
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

TextField(
  controller: textEditingController,
  onSubmitted: (value){
    city = textEditingController.text;
    getWeather();
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is add TextField for the user to input the city name.
the way you can do that is shown before. The next thing you have to do is write a function to fetch weather data with city name.

```
var url =
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\$city&units=metric&appid=apikey';

class CityWeatherData {
  final String city, temprateure, humidity; //...

  CityWeatherData({
    this.city,
    this.temprateure,
    this.humidity,
    // ...
  });

  factory CityWeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CityWeatherData(
      city: json['city'],
      humidity: json['city']['humidity'],
      temprateure: json['city']['temp'],
      // ...
    );
  }
}

Future<CityWeatherData> fetchWeatherDataBycity() async {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return CityWeatherData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('failed to fetch data.');
  }
}
```

I depending on the JSON data you get you have to edit the fromjson method.

I hope this was helpful!